# Rails partial view set value of form field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

Okay so I am quite new to Rails and am trying to do the following without success:

I have an Object (from my Active Record) containing a project, which contains n sub-projects, which contain n tasks. Now for each of these I want a partial view.

So I render from the project view the sub-project with the following code:

```
<%= render(:partial => 'subproject', :collection =>  @project.sub_projects) %>
```

Within my sub-project partial view called _subproject.rhtml (adding the code to a good ol Rails 1.2.3 project), so I can access the data like this:

```
<%= subproject.name %>
```

That will print out the name alright but when I try to generate a textfield this won't work:

```
<%= text_field 'subproject', 'name' %>
```

But this will:

```
<%= text_field 'subproject', 'name', :value => subproject.name %>
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

Edit: Changed title due to my problem is not passing the value but displaying it within a form field.

---

Edit2: As requested my controller code:

```
@project = Project.find(params[:id])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write this:

```
<%= render(:partial => 'subproject', :collection =>  @project.sub_projects) %>
```

as

```
<%= render :partial => @project.sub_projects %>
```

This will render every sub project with the `sub_projects/_sub_project.html.erb` partial.  A little shortcut.

This:

```
<%= text_field 'subproject', 'name' %>
```

Says create a text_field called: subproject[name], but doesn't give it a value.  You need to pass the value you want to set (the code that works).

The more idiomatic way of doing this now is with form_for:

```
<% form_for @subproject do |f| %> 
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
<% end %>
```

Or if you're using formtastic (https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic), which is fantastic, you'd write:

```
<% semantic_form_for @subproject do |f| %> 
    <%= f.input :name %>
<% end %>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your suggestions I implemented the nicer form_for code thing is though, that the value still doesn't get set. When I use the code in the partial view above (the one generating the project html code) the value gets set. Do you know why that happens?

Comment: My view code I already posted, in my controller as far as my Ruby knowledge tells me a member variable is used to hold the value and then is used in the view. But when I try to render partial within a view my 'sub partial' doesn't seem to render the way as documented. And I am using v1.2.3 of Rails (plus I am quite new to Ruby( on Rails))..

Comment: Hey I figured it out, I am using multiple models (which I didn't think of worth to mention..) so my problem is figuring out how to implement multiple models in one form and I found some links about that.. But thanks for giving me the input about the form_for brought me onto the page and idea about the multi model thing and I now have some nicer code too ;-)